# Äquivalente Redewendung zum norwegischen »går det tretten av på dusinet« (»gibt es zu dreizehn im Dutzend«)

Tags: idiom, phrase-request

Gestern las ich in einem norwegischen Zeitungsartikel den folgenden Satz:

> Selvtitulerte digitaliseringseksperter som skråsikkert forteller om
>   hvordan samfunnet vil utvikle seg **går det tretten av på dusinet**.

Diesen kann man übersetzen mit:

> Selbsternannte Digitalisierungsexperten, die absolut sicher vorhersagen, wie die Gesellschaft sich entwickeln wird, **gibt es zu dreizehn im Dutzend**.

Gibt es zu *dreizehn im Dutzend* eine ähnliche schöne Redewendung, die im Deutschen üblich ist?

Comment: Kannst Du bitte Deiner Frage hinzufügen, was die norwegische Redewendung ausdrückt und welche Teile davon Du behalten möchtest?

Comment: Sie drückt aus: _zu viele_. Behalten: Beliebig viel oder wenig.

Comment: "mehr als man brauchen kann"   ist zwar nicht so schön wie 13/12 trifft aber vielleicht die Bedeutung der redewendung gut

Comment: Oder auch "mehr als genug"  ist etwas weniger salopp als mein Vorschlag zuvor

Comment: Zusatzbemerkung: Ich habe gestern den Autor des norwegischen Artikels gefragt, woher die norwegische Redewendung kommt. Er sagt: Die genaue Herkunft ist unbekannt; sie ist recht neu, belegt seit den 1920er Jahren. Ein Beispiel: Ein Bäcker verkaufte seine Brötchen im Dutzend, und legte dann ein dreizehntes in die Tüte.

Answer (score 6):

Im Deutschen gibt es folgende Redewendung:

> ... gibt es **wie Sand am Meer**.

Das trifft die Bedeutung recht gut, wenn ich deine Erklärung richtig verstanden habe.
Das entspricht etwa dem Englischen

> a dime a dozen.

Comment: Na ja: "Sand am Meer" bedeutet eigentlich eher "*unendlich viele*". Aber es ist dennoch die beste Entsprechung der Redewendung.

Answer (score 3):

Zwar nicht sehr häufig aber dennoch bekannt ist möglicherweise vom französischen *Treize a la douzaine* oder aus dem Niederdeutschen hergeleitet auch eine deutsche Variante:

> [Der dreizehnte im Dutzend](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/Wander/call_wbgui_py_from_form?sigle=Wander&mode=Volltextsuche&lemid=WD00619#XWD00619)

Allerdings konnte ich nur wenig Fundstellen neueren Datums finden:

> - Ein weiterer mittelmäßiger Politkarrierist, wie es in Österreich dreizehn im Dutzend davon gibt? <sup>[Kommentar im derStandard.at](http://derstandard.at/1282978717958/Kopf-des-Tages-Von-Rot-zu-Gruen-und-wieder-zurueckhttp://)</sup>
> - Denn das Sprichwort sagt: „Dreizehn ist des Teufels Dutzend“. Daher auch: „Er ist der Dreizehnte im Dutzend“ – er ist überflüssig.<sup>[Eßlinger Zeitung](https://www.esslinger-zeitung.de/region/kultur_artikel,-dreizehn-ist-des-teufels-dutzend-_arid,712744.html)</sup>

Etwas gebräuchlicher könnte man die Überzahl an Experten vielleicht so beschreiben:

> Selbsternannte Experten gibt es **im Überfluss**.

Comment: Interessant, daß es doch sehr ähnliche Ausdrücke gibt.

Comment: Zu deinem Beispiel aus der Eßlinger Zeitung: Ich verstehe es eher als „überflüssig“, wie es ja auch da steht, also etwa wie „das fünfte Rad am Wagen“. Das besagt nicht, dass es von ihm eine große Anzahl gibt.

Comment: Lokal hat man bei den Uhrenproduzenten  im Schwarzwald von einem "Schwenninger Dutzend" geredet. D.h man hat für jede Dutzend Verpackungen von Produkten noch eine dazugelegt, was ja auch dreizehn macht.

Comment: @Beta: das ist eine weitere Bedutung, die m.E. hier aber nicht zutrifft.

Comment: @Takkat Ja etwas anders ist die Bedeutung, daher nur ein Kommentar. Die Redewendung ist immerhin nicht unbedingt positiv, sie drückt auch ein unerwüschte Übermass aus. Das Verfahren war ein Mittel um Abkommen in Preiskartellen herumzugehen.

Answer (score 2):

Eine ähnliche Redewendung im Sinne von *schön* gibt es meines Wissens im Deutschen nicht. Aber man könnte (auch umgangssprachlich) verwenden:

> ..., gibt es zuhauf [dutzendweise], [en masse], [haufenweise], [massenhaft].

Answer (score 0):

Übersetz' einfach ins Niederländische - Da gibt es dieselbe Redewendung ;)

> Er gaan er dertien in een dozijn. (Wörtlich: Es gehen dreizehn auf ein Dutzend.)

Im Schwedischen gibt es dasselbe, das Deutsche kennt diese Redewendung aber so nicht. Wir sagen

> Da gehen zwölf auf ein Dutzend

wenn wir ausdrücken wollen, dass etwas "nichts Besonderes" ist. Sehr verbreitet ist diese Wendung meiner Erfahrung nach aber nicht.

Wenn es unbedingt eine Redewendung mit "Dutzend" sein soll, kannst du versuchen

> gibt's im Dutzend billiger

zu verwenden - Das drückt aus, dass es davon wirklich genug gibt, kommt also deinem Original ziemlich nahe.

Genauso kann man (ohne Verwendung einer Redensart)

> ... gibt es dutzendweise

sagen, ich habe auch schon die Wendung

> ... ich will doch keinen Dutzendmensch heiraten

gelesen, die Ähnliches zum Ausdruck bringt.

Comment: -1 es gibt die Redewendung schon im Deutschen http://woerterbuchnetz.de/Wander/call_wbgui_py_from_form?sigle=Wander&mode=Volltextsuche&lemid=WD00619#XWD00619 - sie ist halt auch bei uns nicht mehr so sehr gebräuchlich, wie das vermutlich auch für das Norwegische und Holländische gilt.

Comment: @Takkat ***gibt***, weil in einem Wörterbuch von 1867 gefunden? Naja.

Comment: Die Verbreitung mag ja regional und Dir noch nie über den Weg gekommen sein, aber einfach zu behaupten es gäbe die Redewendung nicht und man solle auf das Holländische zurückgreifen, geht gar nicht.

Comment: @takkat Fakt ist: Es gibt diese Redewendung m. W. [heute] nicht [mehr] im Deutschen. Mir ist sie zumindestens noch nie untergekommen. Einem Fremdsprachler vorzugaukeln, er könne diese Wendung wörtlich übersetzen und erwarten, verstanden zu werden, weil sie in einem alten Wörterbuch steht, geht überhaupt nicht. Im Holländischen habe ich diese Wendung schon gehört, im Schwedischen auch. Im Deutschen nicht.

Comment: Dann schreib halt, dass man das heute dort wo Du wohnst nicht mehr sagt, oder dass Du das noch nie gehört hast, oder was auch immer. Dass man es im Deutschen gar nicht kennt, wird schon durch die beiden Zitate  in meiner Antwort widerlegt. Was wäre Dein Vorschlag für eine Übersetzung dieser Redewendung?